# Implementing a custom datatype in Sympy

Tags: python, math, sympy

I want to perform calculations with a binary operation (`Tensor`) that takes two non-commutative arguments, converts them into something like a pair, and then does funny things when I multiply these pairs.

```
# a, b, c, d are non-commutative
Tensor(a, b) * Tensor(c, d) == Tensor(a*c, d*b)  # yes, in this order
```

Furthermore, I want all integer constants to be taken modulo 2.

```
-Tensor(a, b) == Tensor(a, b)
2*Tensor(a, b) == 0
Tensor(2*a, b) == 0
```

---

My shot at doing this:

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy.core.expr import Expr

class Tensor(Expr):
    __slots__ = ['is_commutative']

    def __new__(cls, l, r):
        l = sp.sympify(l)
        r = sp.sympify(r)
        obj = Expr.__new__(cls, l, r)
        obj.is_commutative = False
        return obj

    def __neg__(self):
        return self

    def __mul__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Tensor):
            return Tensor(self.args[0] * other.args[0], other.args[1] * self.args[1])
        elif other.is_number:
            if other % 2 == 0:
                return 0
            else:
                return self
        else:
            return sp.Mul(self, other)


x, y = sp.symbols('x, y', commutative=False)

Ym = Tensor(y, 1) - Tensor(1, y)
Yp = Tensor(y, 1) + Tensor(1, y)
Xm = Tensor(x, 1) - Tensor(1, x)

d1 = Ym * Yp + Xm * 0
print(d1)
print(sp.expand(d1))

d2 = Xm * Ym
print(d2)
print(sp.expand(d2))
```

Output:

```
(Tensor(1, y) + Tensor(y, 1))**2
Tensor(1, y**2) + 2*Tensor(y, y) + Tensor(y**2, 1)
(Tensor(1, x) + Tensor(x, 1))*(Tensor(1, y) + Tensor(y, 1))
Tensor(1, x)*Tensor(1, y) + Tensor(1, x)*Tensor(y, 1) + Tensor(x, 1)*Tensor(1, y) + Tensor(x, 1)*Tensor(y, 1)
```

- Test #1 is correct.
- Test #2 has a term `2*Tensor(y, y)` which should be zero (since I'm doing all calculations modulo 2, and, 2 % 2 == 0). How do I enforce that?
- Test #3 is correct.
- Test #4 does not multiply different `Tensor`s at all. `Tensor(1, x)*Tensor(1, y)` should be `Tensor(1, y*x)`, for example. How do I enforce that?

---

Context (if you're interested in why I'm doing this):

This is for calculating a bimodule resolution of an algebra over a `char=2` field. A bimodule resolution of an algebra `R` over a field `K` is a minimal projective resolution of the same algebra `R` over its enveloping algebra `R⊗R^op`. Here `op` means "multiplication works in the opposite direction". The enveloping algebra has both left and right action on the algebra:

```
(a⊗b)*r == a*r*b
r*(a⊗b) == b*r*a
```

There is a theorem that simplifies calculations in the case where a minimal projective resolution of the algebra over the field is known. Still, they are quite tedious and I want to stop doing them manually.

Comment: I have outlined a solution [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/11918).